# Is it possible to send customized advertising PDU in Android 6.0?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

By doing some preliminary research I'm getting conflicting results. It appears that some believe customizable advertising PDUs stopped being a future of Android around as early as Android 3.0.

Is it possible? If so, do I have to use a 3rd party library, like those from Github or there are ready-made APIs which comes with packages installed/installable in Android Studio?